# What hardware technology (GPU, FPGA) is fastest at generating RSA keys?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure

I'm interested in generating RSA keys in rapid succession and am looking for the correct hardware to so.  I think what I'm looking for is very similar to a brute force attack on RSA keys, but my purpose is to generate keys that contain a text string when output in ASCII / BASE58 or similar forms.

I believe I need hardware that is able to multiply (determine the square of) a given value very quickly.  (I'm still learning RSA key generation, so correct me if I'm mistaken)

I'm looking at a variety of technologies such as OpenCL (for [video cards](http://developer.amd.com/tools/graphics-development/) [etc](https://developer.nvidia.com/tools/Development)), and possibly even FPGAs.  I don't know if any ASICs are available for this purpose, but that would be ideal if they existed.

**Question**

So, what hardware technologies (not products) is the fastest (and available for consumers) to generate RSA keys in rapid succession ?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @Polynomial I'm interested in learning what *technology* is appropriate.  e.g. Are stream processors in a GPU more important or is memory (to handle larger numbers), or is GPU speed in MHZ?  I'm not looking for a product, just technology name.

Comment: An FPGA is always going to be the fastest hardware at performing *any* task, as it is simply re-mappable silicon dedicated to the task in question.

Comment: @lynks I disagree. An ASIC would be better. FPGAs are used because they are re-mappable and readily available for cheap. I'm not saying FPGA isn't the right answer, but I wouldn't go as far as saying an FPGA is "always going to be the fastest hardware"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is about economics. Otherwise, there is a simple answer: whatever system you use to generate RSA key pairs, just buy two of them and you will generate twice as many key pairs per second. So your question must be:

***For a given budget*, which kind of technology (GPU, FPGA) will help generate the most RSA key pairs in a given time frame ?**

Then we can begin to give some answers. On the paper, the FPGA will be better. Indeed, the FPGA is reconfigurable, which means that you can make a dedicated circuit and do not have to "pay" for parts you do not need. The FPGA has a fixed overhead because of its reconfigurability: namely, you cannot clock it as high as you would with a fixed, non-reconfigurable circuit (by a factor of roughly 2 or 3). On the other hand, a GPU will come with a lot of things that you do not need for RSA key pair generation, including a lot of RAM management. The really killer point is the lack of wide multiplication in GPU: RSA is about big integers and multiplications, and it really needs multipliers which can multiply, for instance, 64-bit integers, yielding 128-bit results. A basic CPU (that from a PC) can do that. GPU are optimized for floating-point operations and will be limited to, at best, 53 bits of precision for the result.

Some people have nonetheless tried to do RSA on GPU; see for instance [this article](https://www.cs.tcd.ie/John.Waldron/owenHarrison/publications/PKonGPU_eurocrypt.pdf) (it is about RSA private key *usage*, not generation, but we can consider the results as roughly applicable because RSA key pair generation is mostly primality testing, which is modular exponentiation). A GPU appears to be, very roughly, about 4 times as efficient as a CPU of comparable price.

For FPGA, there are a number of documented implementations (e.g. [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=6128530)) but comparisons with GPU are hard because they do not work with the same units.

GPU are consumer electronics: they really are off-the-shelf and anybody can buy some. If you want to build a machine which generate RSA key pairs, you will get a working system in much less time by using GPU than by using FPGA; however, using basic CPU (i.e. a few PC) will get you there even much faster. If you really have a hard bandwidth goal and are ready to invest quite a lot in development, then FPGA or dedicated ASIC are the way to go. That's what [Hardware Security Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) vendors do.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest would be purpose built hardware that implements the algorithms in hardware.  It would probably be possible to implement a pretty quick algorithm on GPUs as well, but if speed really matters, then I'd recommend getting something purpose built since there could also be key leaking issues with a GPU.